# Removing included CSS file that doesn’t exist

Tags: plugins, css, uploads

I tried to install a premium plugin for divi icons, But it wasn’t installed successfully.

There is a CSS file added to the homepage https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/aspengrove-icons/multicolor.css?ver=1.1.1

That CSS file doesn’t exist and I want to remove it, But I don’t know where it’s added.

How to remove this from homepage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="ags-divi-icons-multicolor-css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/aspengrove-icons/multicolor.css?ver=1.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I checked the plugins folder and there is no folder with that plugin name.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for (consider looking into the dequeue functions). Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt, I need to find the code that adds it, Then remove it